# Laravel @yield showing content with HTML tags

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, yield

I'm new to Laravel and I faced this issue, when I'm using @yield('content') to view some HTML, the out put will be the exact contact with decoding it into HTML.

Here is my code :

```
@yield('content',"<p>This is a great starting point for new custom pages</p>")
```

And the out put is : `<p>This is a great starting point for new custom pages</p>`

And here is a screenshot :

[image]

Can someone help me know what's going on please?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Laravel, the `@yield` directive is looking to pull the `@section` that you note up from whichever file is producing the html.  When you pull in the `@section`, it is formatted as proper html on the page.

So, if you had a section like this:

```
@section('paragraph')
    <p>here is some text</p>
@stop
```

And pulled this in a `@yield` statement:

```
@yield('paragraph')
```

This would simply output the html:

> here is some text

What you have done with this:

```
@yield('content',"<p>This is a great starting point for new custom pages</p>")
```

is to supply *default* text to display on the screen if the 'content' section is unavailable.  **This text is escaped, thus you are seeing the html tags**.

Answer (score 1):

@Mousa Alfhaily, You do not have to pass the return value with the html tags
If you want to paragraph the return value... Then you do that at where the content is been rendered

```
@yield('content',"<p>This is a great starting point for new custom pages</p>")
```

it should be

```
@yield('content')
```

then your

```
@section('content')
$var = "This is a great starting point for new custom pages";
<p>
 {{$var}}
</p>
@endsection
```

Answer (score 1):

The `@section` directive, defines a section of content, while the `@yield` directive is used to display the contents of a given section.

So, if you had **@section** like- `@section('paragraph')`...`@endsection`.

then, **@yield** must be like - `@yield('paragraph')`

> Example

In `@yield`directives -

```
@yield('content')
```

In `@section` directives-

```
@section('content')
...
your html content
...
@endsection
```